# Determine the biggest summand of a special sum of binomial coeffients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I got stucked in an exercise with an sum of special binomial coeffients. The goal is to determine the biggest summand of the following sum.
$$\sum_{k=\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{n-1-k} $$
Does anyone have an idea how to figure out the correct answer for this question?
Greetings.

Comment: To answer these kinds of questions, it sometimes helps to compute the fraction of the $k$th and $(k+1)$st summand and check when it is smaller or larger than $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$R(k) = \frac{{\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n-1-k}}}{{\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{k+1}{n-1-(k+1)}}}$$

as the ratio between the terms. Expanding, you have that

$$R(k) = \frac{(2+2k-n)(3+2k-n)}{(k-n)(k-n+1)}$$

Now check when $R(k)\leq 1$, which happens when $3k-2n+3\leq 0$ or $k\leq \frac{2n-3}{3}$. Similarly, for $k\geq \frac{2n-3}{3}$, $R(k)\geq 1$.

In other words, the summands before $\frac{2n-3}{3}$ are non decreasing, and the summands after are non increasing. Which tells you that the maximum summand happens at $\frac{2n-3}{3}$. However, since this can be fractional, then the maximum happens at either $\lfloor \frac{2n-3}{3} \rfloor$ or $\lceil \frac{2n-3}{3} \rceil$